# How to custom imbricated forms with sf2

Tags: php, symfony

I have got a form with a collection of objects.
My problem is that I need to custom the display of the collected objects.
For now, I only have the basis template with ,  and so on. But I want to add some tags like `<h3>`, `<tr><td>`...
Where can I configure the display of an imbricated form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete chapter how to customize a form.

[Symfony2 Customize form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Comment: I'm quite ashamed. I rounded on the doc site for hours searching "Form", "imbricated form", "template form"... but forgot "customize form"...

Comment: Its not so easy but when you understood the customization its very cool.

Comment: Yep, it is not easy. It makes me hate twig a little more.

Comment: It is so uneasy that I can't understand how does it work to handle the template of my own item collection.

Comment: I got more informations here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159542/how-to-customize-data-prototype-in-symfony2-form-collections
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html